# How to debug crashing iOS Safari when Web Inspector and the logs don't indicate anything?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari, web-inspector

Are there any strategies for troubleshooting a page that crashes iOS Safari when

- Appears to be a problem rendering - the page starts to load/render then fail
- Only on iPhone. iPad is just fine. Both iPhone 5s and 4s.
- Web Inspector in desktop Safari closes immediately after iOS Safari closes
- Nothing concrete in the crash logs for Safari
- The iOS simulator seems to be fine

If so, what can I do? I can't give any concrete code for the page as I have no idea what is causing it - it would just be a link to the page.

Comment: a link to such a page would be cool. Id see if it crashes for me too.. maybe we find something

Comment: the current page is http://www.itownchurch.com/messages

Comment: "Nothing concrete in the crash logs for Safari" - how do you see those ?

Answer (score -1):

Check out Fiddler, I use it mainly on a PC but there seems to be a Mac build as well. It may help give you a bit more insight into the traffic coming in and out of your machine. Although if the page crashes Safari the issue may be on your machine in which case Fiddler wont help much but its worth a shot to see if some of the web traffic is causing the issue.

http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono

Can you be a bit more specific as to the page, what it does, why it may cause a crash, did you write it or is it a page out there that you are trying to access?

Comment: this is for an iphone - i can't use fiddler with that. and its not a network problem.

Comment: countered vote as this is very valid approach (though I use charles web proxy)

Comment: that would show you the raw HTTP requests, all headers and the servers responses

Comment: you can easily set your mac as proxy btw

Comment: if I give a website on webkit mobile a 401 back from an ajax call. the browser hangs sometimes. It isnt a network issue but the headers make safari misbehave.

Comment: so I remain firm that this is a valid approach and especially a valid answer to YOUR rather 'vague' question :D

Comment: @Daij-Djan - why would iPad just be fine?